# can not get right cassandra metrics value

Tags: cassandra

when monitoring cassandra metrics,met this problem:
the value of org.apache.cassandra.db.DynamicEndpointSnitch.Scores is empty

I want to get this value,because it stores the all the node in cluster.

this value is right in cassandra v2.1,but not cassandra3.4,cassandra3.5

I have read the 3.4,3.5 code,this property are not changed.
I dont know why this value is empty?

and I see the org.apache.cassandra.db.Storage.Proxy.SchemaVersions stores the

all node.
is this variable'value is right.

thanks in advance!

Comment: get all nodes in cluster is what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its empty (in all versions) until the messaging service is actually used. The dynamic snitch needs to have a latency in the samples reservoir. You can "kick the bucket" and give it something to do:

```
# cqlsh
> select * from system_distributed.repair_history;
```

This will provide you with latency of at least 2 nodes (RF of 2) and gives something for samples & scores.

Comment: actually I want to get all nodes in cluster,and I found that the variable cannot store all nodes,just 2 of 3.and I doubt that can get the right value when add/remove node,it cannot update timely.so my question is which variable that can get all nodes in cluster from java MBean

Answer (score 0):

Have fixed the problem.

use the following attribute

> org.apache.cassandra.db.StorageService.LiveNodes